# prove the limit at infinity by epsilon delta definition

Tags: complex-analysis, limits

Prove:
$\lim_{z\to\infty}{z^2+7} = \infty$. The question wants me to use the definition of neighborhood of infinity.

I know I might have to use $w = {1\over z}$, and I know that the neighborhood of infinity should be like $|z| > {1\over \epsilon}$ But I don't know how to continue my proof?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $M>0$

Then $|z|^2+7 \geq |z|^2-7$

So for $N=M+7$.

For $|z|>N$  we have that $|z|^2+7>(M+7)^2-7=M^2+14M+42>M$

Comment: Thanks first. But I would like to say, it seems that you did not use the definition of a neighborhood of infinity?

Comment: @Cooper the definition of the limit at infinity in complex analysis is that which i used with M,N...note that every open neighborhood of infinity has the form $\{z:|z|>M\}$ ,$M>0$

Comment: Alright, I see. Thank you

Comment: Why is this answer downvoted..? if someone downvotes an answer at least he/her must give a reason or point a potential mistake in the answer